# JButton click to write to file

Tags: jbutton, actionlistener

Hi guys I'm having trouble understanding how to implement ActionListeners into my code, I am trying to have it when my jbutton1 is clicked that it's able to write out to a text document. Any help given will be much appreciated.

```
package loanapplication;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


class SheetListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println("The123 Laury");
        writer.println("My balls");
        writer.close();
    }
      public JButton createSheet()
       {
        JButton jButton1 = new JButton("Submit");
        SheetListener listener = new SheetListener();
        jButton1.addActionListener(listener);
        return jButton1;
       }

}
public class Loan_App extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    public Loan_App() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Loan Application");

        jLabel2.setText("First Name");

        jLabel3.setText("Last Name");

        jLabel4.setText("Address Line 1");

        jLabel5.setText("Address Line 2");

        jLabel6.setText("County");

        jLabel7.setText("Loan Amount");

        jLabel11.setText("Installment Amount");

        jButton1.setText("Submit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(93, 93, 93)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                        .addComponent(jLabel11)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(146, 146, 146))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(258, 258, 258))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                    .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

        JButton jButton1;
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loan_App.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loan_App.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loan_App.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loan_App.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Loan_App().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
    private ActionListener listener;

    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I started trying different things and I believe that I've made progress but I'm utterly lost at what to do now, I have updated the code in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

from the code you have given. i think you cant view the calculate button that you have defined in the main function, first of all you have to add the component to the frame or panel.

and for implementing the action listener go through the below links [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html),
[example](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html)